# How to amend Powerpoint Chart Title text using VBA

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint 2013 presentation with several charts on a slide. I want to amend the charts title but can't figure out how to select the text.

`Activepresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart 2").Chart.Title = "some text"` doesn't change anything. If I prefix that line with `Set` it gives "*Compile error: Invalid use of property*"

`ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "some text"`  gives "*Run-time error '-2147024809 #80070057#': The specified value is out of range*"

The chart title is two lines with a mixture of text sizes. It entire chart has been copied from Excel. The result I need is to amend the second half of that title programmatically.

In Excel `Sheets("Sheet 1").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Name` returns the name but `Sheets("Sheet 1").ChartObjects("Chart 2").HasTitle` gives "*Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incomplete; you need `Chart`, which you have in one place but not the others, the chart element is `ChartTitle` not `Title`, and you need to specify what subelement gets the new text (`Text`):

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart 2").Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "some text"
```

Between `Shapes` or `ChartObject` and any property or method of a chart, you need `Chart`:

```
Sheets("Sheet 1").ChartObjects("Chart 2").HasTitle
```

fails, but

```
Sheets("Sheet 1").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.HasTitle
```

returns True or False.

This is harder without a macro recorder in PowerPoint (there was one until Office 2007 removed it), so you need to use Excel's, and then hack away to make it fit into PowerPoint VBA.